# Запрос INSERT INTO выполняется не правильно в asyncpg

Tags: python, postgresql, discord.py

Я пытаюсь выполнить запрос с вставкой необходимой информации для бота, так как я новичёк, большая часть кода не моя. И поэтому я не могу просто вырезать этот запрос и сделать его вручную.

Самое странное что в pgAdmin4 этот запрос выполняется без ошибок, однако в коде он выдаёт ошибку

> asyncpg.exceptions.NotNullViolationError: значение NULL в столбце "numip" отношения "servers" нарушает ограничение NOT NULL
>
> DETAIL:  Ошибочная строка содержит (0, null, null, null, null).

Собственно сам код (обрезал как мог). Проблемное место на строке 35, или же там где написано

> ```
>    conn.execute("""
>    INSERT INTO servers (id, numip, maxpl)
>    VALUES (1, '127.0.0.1', 0) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
>        ;""")
> ```

```
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import discord
import asyncpg

bot_intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot_intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix='',
    description="описание",
    case_insensitive=False,
    help_command=None,
    status=discord.Status.invisible,
    intents=bot_intents,
    fetch_offline_members=True
)

bot.ready_for_commands = False


async def create_pool():
    """Создает таблицы в бд, если они уже есть - загружает их"""

    bot.pool = await asyncpg.create_pool('postgres://test:123123123@localhost:5432/postgres')
    async with bot.pool.acquire() as conn:
        await conn.execute("""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS servers (
                id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
                domen TEXT,
                numip CIDR NOT NULL DEFAULT '127.0.0.1',
                alias TEXT,
                maxpl INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
            );""")

        conn.execute("""
        INSERT INTO servers (id, numip, maxpl)
        VALUES (1, '127.0.0.1', 0) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
            ;""")

        query = await conn.fetch("SELECT * FROM servers;")

    bot.sunpings = {}
    bot.servers = {}
    for i in query:
        bot.servers.update({i.get("id"): dict(i)})

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await create_pool()

    print("\nЗапуск успешен")

    update_db.start()
    bot.ready_for_commands = True
    bot.started_at = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    bot.app_info = await bot.application_info()


@tasks.loop(minutes=5, loop=bot.loop)
async def update_db():
    """Обновляет ДБ каждые 5 минут"""

    async with bot.pool.acquire() as conn:
        await conn.execute("""
            INSERT INTO servers
            (id)
            VALUES {}
            ON CONFLICT
                DO NOTHING
        ;""".format(", ".join([f"({u})" for u in bot.servers])))

        for data in bot.servers.copy().values():
            await conn.execute("""
                UPDATE servers
                SET total = {}
                WHERE id = {}
            ;""".format(data["total"], data["id"]))


try:
    bot.loop.run_until_complete(bot.start('ODM0MTc5Mzk5NDIyNzA1NzI0.YH9IGw.iB285ySqDOMlzFVDnc-NICFWzT4'))
except KeyboardInterrupt: pass
```

Comment: А почему код работает с таблицей servers а в сообщении об ошибке фигурирует sunservers ? А еще в сообщении об ошибке написано что вставляется строка состоящая из нулей и NULL, но похожего insert в коде вообще нет. Есть только странный insert в update_db который вроде как вставляет только колонку id, но при этом значений может больше одного, смотря что там придет в bot.servers

Comment: @Mike 1. sunservers просто были изменены на servers с оригинального кода. 2. Я не знаю, поэтому я здесь. 3. Это осталось от кода который я копипастил и изменял под себя вот тут оригинал _https://github.com/NWordCounter/bot_ а тут именно та версия которую я использовал для основы бота _https://github.com/PerchunPak/sunshinedsbot_

Comment: А в сообщении об ошибке не выводится номер строки где она произошла ? 1. В общем найдите виновную строку. Судя по сообщению об ошибке в таблицу пытается вставится полностью пустая строка. Надо будет найти откуда эта строка приходит. Возможно что то не так с входными данными из которых берется список серверов

Comment: Да я как то не посмотрел на строку куда ссылается трейсбэк, она ведёт на строку 64, то что я ещё не трогал и отложил пока пофикшу ту ошибку.